# Stored procedure not executing from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure from my `ASP.Net` code behind, but it does not work as desired. The same SP is running fine when i execute it in the `SQL Server Management Studio`. The code is :

```
SqlConnection con = new   SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString);
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_utmerge", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userId", Txt_Userid.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Txt_Uname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@designation", Txt_Design.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", Txt_Dept.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contact_no", Txt_Cntct.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Txt_Email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", Txt_Addrs.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", Txt_DOB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Txt_Pwd.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.close();
```

The Stored Procedure is:

```
 USE [ABC]
 GO 
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_utmerge]    Script         
Date:12/12/2016 11:20:04 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_utmerge]@userId nvarchar(10),@username   nvarchar(50),@designation nvarchar(50),@dept nvarchar(20),@contact_no nvarchar(20),@email nvarchar(MAX),@address nvarchar(100),@dob varchar(20),@password nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
merge Teachermast as target
using (select userId, username, designation, dept, contact_no, email,  address, dob, password from UserMast where usertype = 3) 
as source(userId, username, designation, dept, contact_no, email, address,  dob, password)
on target.teacher_code = source.userId
when not matched by target then
insert (teacher_code, teacher_name, designation, dept_code, contact_no, email, address, dob, password)
values (source.userId, source.username, source.designation, source.dept, source.contact_no, source.email, source.address, source.dob, source.password);

END
```

The SSMS result is as:

```
USE [ABC]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_utmerge]
        @userId = N'T0006',
        @username = N'abc',
        @designation = N'Teacher ',
        @dept = N'EIC',
        @contact_no = N'9632563256',
        @email = N'abc@yahoo.com',
        @address = N'97 xyz street',
        @dob = N'31/08/1990',
        @password = N'12345'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

Return Value 0

What would be a possible solution to this issue?

Comment: Zero output does not mean that it's not executed. You don't have `RETURN` command in your SP. Default return value is 0 - that's what you  have. It has nothing to do with _rows affected_ or so on. It's an absolutely separate value like an `exit` code of windows console app. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx

Comment: "does not work as desired" gives us no clue as to what you expect. What do you expect?

Comment: Hopefully the code that follows does... But for convenience:  I am trying to  insert into table 2 all field values of a row from table A, where all values in a column A in table 1 that satisfy a condition on column B of table 1 ,but do not exist in table 2. Check the SP

Comment: You are reading `RETURN` value of your SP. But you don't set it. You don't have `RETURN <some non-zero integer value>` code in your SP - that's why you're getting _default zero return value_. `MERGE` statement does not set `RETURN` value.

Comment: yes Ivan i'm struggling with that. should I use the output statement  like OUTPUT Teachermast.teacher_code, Teachermast.teacher_name...... after declaring the parameters or output.merge .... if that makes senese

Comment: @AnitaMathew What do you need to get from this sp? ID of new record if it was inserted?

Comment: all the fields of the added record.. i.e. teacher_code, teacher_name, designation, dept_code, contact_no, email, address, dob, password

Comment: @AnitaMathew are you okay with the fact that it will be a result set with many columns? Not a scalar value `@return_value` (which will be totally unnecessary and senseless in described scenario).

Comment: basically, all I want is the added record to reflect in the 2 table which is not happening from the code behind ..currently

Comment: So you've _almost_ told us the issue. Are you saying that when you run this from ASP code, , `Teachermast` is neither updated or inserted but when you run it from SSMS, some records are updated/inserted? Can we exclude the return value from the discussion or do you also want to capture that? My first suggestion is to use Profiler to capture the SQL. http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29284/how-to-profile-stored-procedures  In the last question like this that I saw, they were writing to the wrong database. Profiler is a bit of effort but you'll see with your own eyes what's going on.

Comment: Tried your suggestion ..its being written to the correct database..but still no positive results